# Subject + be + verb + ed, what grammar structure is it?

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives, past-tense

I have a question about this sentence:

> Yesterday I was awarded.

I don't understand: is it a passive sentence?
Or is it: Subject + was + adjective. Is the word `awarded` an adjective?

Same question about this sentence:

> I am imprisoned for my religious beliefs.

Is `imprisoned` an adjective or is it a passive sentence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the verb "to award" used according to the following syntax.

> award (sb) sth, award sth (to sb) [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/award_2)

In your sentence the voice is the passive voice; you can see from the entry in the dictionary that you need an object;

- Yesterday I was awarded a new compensation/a prize for my work on…/an honorary degree/…

---

"Imprisoned" is a past participle employed in the passive voice. Since you can say "They imprisoned me for my religious beliefs." the -ed form is not an adjective.

Comment: What is the difference between "broken" and "imprisoned"? I could say:  their relationship was broken, does it mean they broke the relationship? I saw broken is a adjective

Comment: @Edoardo 1/ The frontier between recognized adjectives and past participles used as adjectives is not a simple one; in verifying to what degree a past participle can share the nature of an adjective, grammarians use sets of criteria characterizing adjectives and check how they apply to the past participle; I am not familiar with this knowledge and apart from that I cannot pinpoint anything in the usage of "imprisoned" that would prevents its classification as a full adjective, and so I share the notion you apparently have that both are adjectives on an equal par; I cannot tell you. (1/2)

Comment: @Edoardo 2/ In some cases, yes, "they" is the agent, but the possibility of the relationship being broken by something else  is not excluded; the case of sentimental relationships, when "they" is most likely the agent, is not the only one.